# CakePHP deleting all records in a table

Tags: cakephp, delete-record

I want to delete all records from my tables using CakePHP syntax, how can I ?

I tried, `deleteAll` but it works with conditions only, the same way for `delete`, Is there any other way, I can empty my tables?

Let me know !

Comment: $this->Model->deleteAll(’1 = 1′, false); this is the way to empty all d records of d table in cakephp

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html

I haven't used deleteAll() to delete an entire table, so I don't know whether you can call it without arguments (edit: you can't call it without arguments). However, you could just use

```
$this->Model->deleteAll(array('1 = 1'));
```

However, I think it would be better if you just ran the `TRUNCATE` SQL command via the `query()` method.

```
$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE table;');
```

Comment: As far as I've researched, your second option is indeed the only way to go in Cake.

Comment: @vindia you should be able to use `1 = 1` since it's valid mysql. But the problem is that it would be quite slow I think. Compared to `TRUNCATE` anyway

Comment: It should actually be `$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE TABLE tablename');` where `tablename` is replaced by your actual table name.

Answer (score 1):

try to set $cascade true in your action as a second parameter , then all records are deleted if dependent is set to true in your model